# drawing a line path in google map with GPS co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-maps, gps

can anyone please tell me how to draw a line path in **[Google-Map](https://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&tab=wl)** using the GPS co-ordinates which i retrieve from database

example of GPS co-ordinates which i get is as shown below

```
10.013566,76.331549
10.013566,76.331463
10.013503,76.331313
10.013482,76.331205
10.013419,76.330926
10.013334,76.330712
10.013313,76.330411
10.013292,76.330175
10.013228,76.329854
10.013144,76.329553
10.013059,76.329296
10.012996,76.329017
10.012869,76.328802
10.012785,76.328545
10.012700,76.328223
10.012679,76.328030
10.012658,76.327837
10.012637,76.327600
10.012573,76.327322
10.012552,76.327043
10.012552,76.326807
10.012510,76.326613
10.012447,76.326399
10.012404,76.326227
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/EPM6A/2/)**

```
function initialize(){
   var center= new google.maps.LatLng(10.012869,76.328802);
   var myOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: center,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
            navigationControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
   }     
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var polylineCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566,76.331549),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566,76.331463),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.013503,76.331313),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.013482,76.331205),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.013419,76.330926),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.013334,76.330712),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.013313,76.330411),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.013292,76.330175),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.013228,76.329854),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.013144,76.329553),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.013059,76.329296),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012996,76.329017),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012869,76.328802),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012785,76.328545),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012700,76.328223),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012679,76.328030),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012658,76.327837),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012637,76.327600),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012573,76.327322),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552,76.327043),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552,76.326807),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012510,76.326613),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012447,76.326399),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012404,76.326227),
  ];
  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: polylineCoordinates,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      editable: true
  });

  polyline.setMap(map);    

}



initialize();
```

Comment: set zoom according your requirement

Comment: sir can we use this for dynamic line generation..since i'm taking the co-ordinates from database....which is been updated by my android application. does the map moves along with the movement of cordinates

Comment: I don't about movement of cordinates but you can add co-ordinates to array

Comment: what about the outerframe(with which the map is shown) does it move